# Sonar issue, make variable transient or Serializable

Tags: java, sonar-runner

```
 @SerializedName("next_refill_date")
    @Expose
     public Object nextRefillDate;
```

Sonar issue - Make "nextRefillDate" transient or serializable

I am getting the above sonar issue, why this is happening and how to solve this? Please somebody help